# Set value for ExtJS.form.ComboBox

Tags: extjs, combobox

I have an Ext.grid.EditorGriPanel which has an combobox editor in its columnModel (the store of combox has just only 2 items: enabled/disabled). When a new blank row is inserted to grid, I want the combobox in that column have to be set to a default value (enabled), and the dropdown is not expanded.
I've tried to use
 `grid.colModel.columns[2].editor.select(0)` 
to get the combobox editor and set "enabled" value for it, but it did not work. Another way is using `grid.colModel.columns[2].getCellEditor(rowIndex)`, but it returns an EditorGrid (I was so surprised because the ExtJS 3.3.1 API doesn't have this component).
Could you please help me on this problem?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> When a new blank row is inserted to
>   grid, I want the combobox in that
>   column have to be set to a default
>   value (enabled), and the dropdown is
>   not expanded.

When the new `record` is inserted to the grid's `store`, the value of your column (in the record) needs to be set to "enabled". I'm not sure if you are doing it like this currently? In other words, the value must not be set to the `editor` of the column. Set it directly in the record.

(Also, you can define default values to be used for all records using the `recordType` property of the store - see [ExtJS API documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.Store) for more details - but this is optional.)

Finally, note that the combobox will *not* be displayed immediately after the row is added. The combobox is displayed only when you start editing that particular cell - this is the way `EditorGrid` works in ExtJS. But at least you should get the new row to immediately display the correct value ("enabled") with this advice.